# Is there any chance to detect object using only morphology operations?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, detection, genetic-programming, image-morphology

As in question. Is there any chance to "create" algorithm using only funtions: morphologyEx, threshold, bitwise_xor, bitwise_or, bitwise_and, bitwise_not with different parameters to detect objects (shapes) in image?

I wrote MEP program to find algorithm and i use only this function in function set. Sometimes i can find "not ideal" solution, but it is not, but it only work on trained image

EDIT:
Example:

Input image:
[image]

Reference image (what I want to achieve):
[image]

My result (it isnt great but close):
[image]

But it should find solution for different shape not exactly car.
Is any chance that it can find algorithm that find the same shape in other (not trained) picture. I checked that when i increase size or rotate car found algorithm also work, but it doesnt work on other picture of similar car.

Which operation (using opencv library) can i add to function set to achieve success?

Comment: Perhaps it depends on what you want to detect! Please be specific!

Comment: Probably, but please share at least an example/image, because so far it's too vague.

Comment: @BalajiR I forget to add. I am reading image in greyscale